# C++ While loop ending unexpectedly

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a while loop that runs independently in a second thread in my c++ program, however the loop ends without meeting the conditions I have set.

I have tried setting a counter to keep track of how many times the loop runs and it is different every time, ranging from eight to hundreds of times.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

```
while (ghostPosition.X != playerPosition.X && ghostPosition.Y != playerPosition.Y)
{
    randomDirection = getRandomNumber(1, 5);

    x = ghostPosition.X;
    y = ghostPosition.Y;

    if (randomDirection == 1)
    {
        if (ghostPosition.X > 1)
        {
            COORD oldPosition = { x, y };
            COORD moveTo = { --x, y };
            updateGraphics(oldPosition, moveTo, ghost);
            ghostPosition.X = ghostPosition.X--;
        }
    }
    else if (randomDirection == 2)
    {
        if (ghostPosition.Y < 84)
        {
            COORD oldPosition = { x, y };
            COORD moveTo = { x, ++y };
            updateGraphics(oldPosition, moveTo, ghost);
            ghostPosition.Y = ghostPosition.Y++;
        }
    }
    else if (randomDirection == 3)
    {
        if (ghostPosition.X < 24)
        {
            COORD oldPosition = { x, y };
            COORD moveTo = { ++x, y };
            updateGraphics(oldPosition, moveTo, ghost);
            ghostPosition.X = ghostPosition.X++;
        }
    }
    else if (randomDirection == 4)
    {
        if (ghostPosition.Y > 1)
        {
            COORD oldPosition = { x, y };
            COORD moveTo = { x, --y };
            updateGraphics(oldPosition, moveTo, ghost);
            ghostPosition.Y = ghostPosition.Y--;
        }
    }
}
```

functions called inside loop:

```
int Maze::getRandomNumber(int minimum, int maximum)
{
    int output;
    std::random_device randomDevice;
    std::mt19937 mersenneTwister(randomDevice());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(minimum, maximum);

    return distribution(mersenneTwister);
}
```

The only other function called (updateGraphics) simply modifies the console's output based on the parameters passed. (I don't think that this function is the issue)

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: How do you know the conditions are not meet?  "I don't think this function is the issue"...famous last words.

Comment: Because I've walked through the code and the ghostPosition never matches the playerPosition, but the while loop will still end.

Comment: Why are you using `uniform_real_distribution` for a function that generates integer values with integer bounds when `uniform_int_distribution` is available?

Comment: You repeatedly do `ghostPosition.X = ghostPosition.X--;` (and similar `++`). I'm think that's undefined behavior, and it's confusing either way. If you want to decrement the value, just do `--ghostPosition.X`, with no assignment, postfix decrement and assign is saying "assign the previous value of ghostPosition.X to ghostPosition.X, and decrement ghostPosition.X after reading it", but I'm fairly sure the standard doesn't impose ordering. It could decrement (if the post-decrement comes last), or it could leave the value unchanged (if the assignment happens after).

Comment: On the topic of `uniform_real_distribution`, this is the first program that I've used random with, I suppose I should have done more research on distributions. I also have never used `real` and did not recognize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this loop to execute while the player and ghost positions are different. But that's not the condition you've defined. Your loop executes while the player and ghost X positions are different AND the player and ghost Y positions are different. If either are the same, then the loop will stop. I think you want OR.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you. I misunderstood my logic.

Comment: No worries, I've coded the same bug a hundred times myself!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without some debugging information. Why don't you print out the contents of ghostPosition and playerPosition just before the close of the while loop and post them back.

Also, running the risk of sounding pedantic, you can simply your loop logic by using a swtich statement rather than a multitude of if/else statements.

Comment: Haha, I used a switch statement on a very similar piece of code in a different part of the program, I didn't realize it was better to do so.

Comment: Better is always a matter of taste. I personally think it makes the code easier to read.